# Prevent spring-data-rest from parsing json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I would like to store a post request as a string in a database using spring-data-rest and spring-data-jpa. The problem is that spring tries to convert the json request body to an object. Can I prevent this from happening? Can I configure spring to save the request body as a String?

Below is the entity and the repository.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class DatabaseRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String json;

    public DatabaseRecord(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<DatabaseRecord, Integer> {

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Integer integer);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(DatabaseRecord record);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Iterable<? extends DatabaseRecord> iterable);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void deleteAll();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that spring tries to convert the json request body to an object.

It's main idea of Spring Data REST - translating JSON directly into an instance for ORM mechanism to persist. If it was possible, where would this raw data be saved?

> Can I prevent this from happening?

No, you can't (at least, via Spring Data REST module).

> Can spring I configure spring to save the request body as a string?

You could use a plain Spring MVC controller which will delegate a request to REST repositories but before it does some processing raw data (e.g. saving it into another table).

---

*The line `@RestResource(exported = false)` means excluding the method from the API, it  doesn't effect on the method behaviour (if you tried to use it for such purposes).*